# Логирование POST и GET запросов в Maven-приложении

Tags: post, maven, get, логирование, log4j

Всем доброй ночи. Участвую в учебном проекте по разработке сайта интернет магазина, на меня возложена задача настроить логирование в Maven-проекте с помощью фреймворка log4j. С этим столкнулся впервые, получилось подключить log4j к проекту, создал экземпляр класса Logger, проверил, вызвав его метод info. В процессе настройки файла конфигурации log4j.properties указал путь к файлу, в который будут писаться логи, ну в общем все вроде как работает, логи для теста выводятся на консоль и записываются в файл. Но теперь возник вопрос, как написать логи для Post и Get запросов моего приложения, пролистал кучу инфы, но как-то застопорился и не могу понять как это сделать, а как говорил преподаватель, не можешь решить долго одну проблему, попроси помощи)) Буду благодарен любой информации. Скину например пару запросов (GET возвращает список продуктов в json-формате, POST регистрирует юзера):

```
@GET
@Path("products_full")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
public Response getProductsFull() {
    String json = StorageDao.getInstance(context).getProductsFull();
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(json).build();
}

@POST
@Path("register")
public Response register(String json) {
    User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
    UserWithEncodedPassword userWithEncodedPassword = new UserWithEncodedPassword(
            user.getName(),
            user.getPassword().hashCode(),
            user.getEmail());
    UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
    Result result = new Result();
    if (userDao.getByName(userWithEncodedPassword.getName()) != null) {
        result.setSuccess(false);
        result.setReason("user with the name " + user.getName() + " is already exists");
        String resultStr = gson.toJson(result);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).entity(resultStr).build();
    } else {
        userDao.insert(userWithEncodedPassword);
        result.setSuccess(true);
        result.setId(userWithEncodedPassword.getId());
        String resultStr = gson.toJson(result);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(resultStr).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте в класс контроллера добавить логер, и используйте его для логирования запросов.

Comment: Забыл уточнить, приложение написано с помощью сервлетов, поэтому о каком классе контроллере идет речь? Если о классе, в котором описаны все запросы, то в него я и добавил логер, а трудности возникают с самой логикой реализации логов. Если я конечно правильно понял Ваш ответ.

Comment: Создаёте объект логер: `private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class);` И добавляете его туда, где хотите логировать информацию, например: `public Response getProductsFull() {` `String json = StorageDao.getInstance(context).getProductsFull();` `log.info(json);` `return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(json).build(); }`